# Reconstituting Git History After Manual Copy of Repo Files

Tags: git, version-control

I have a been using a copy of a repository that was manually copied and, unfortunately, has no history. Now an older copy of the repo has been found with a large amount of history. What is my best bet for taking my repo (red) that was created from scratch and incorporating the history of the historical repo (blue).

[image: git]

Comment: If the files path didn't change, you could cherry-pick the revisions that you created on the new repo on top of the revisions from the old repo. If they changed, you could still cherry-pick but some files (new ones) will be written to the wrong "expected" location.

Comment: @Steve What was your solution?  I'm in a similar situation

Comment: The graph implies there is an overlap between the old repo and the new one. Is this true?

Comment: What do you mean "copied without history": do you mean that the repository was copied without a .git directory included?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Yes, it was essentially archived with all git directories deleted.

Answer (score 7):

In your new repository, add the old repository as a remote and fetch it.

```
git remote add old <path or url to the old repo>
git fetch old

A - B - C - D [old/master]

              E - F - G - H [master]
```

E is your initial commit where you copied in all the files.

Check that D and E are similar with `git diff old/master E`. If they are the same, or near enough that it doesn't matter, rebase `master` on top of `old/master`.

```
git rebase old/master

            [old/master]
A - B - C - D - E1 - F1 - G1 - H1 [master]

                E - F - G - H
```

`E1` will now be the diff between the files in `D` and `E`. If the files are identical there will be no `E1` and it will skip to `F1`.

You can then `git push` this back to `old`.

```
git push old master

                                  [old/master]
A - B - C - D - E1 - F1 - G1 - H1 [master]

                E - F - G - H
```

Note that this is just for `master`. If there are other open branches they will also have to be rebased onto the new `master`. Also be sure to check if any tags need to be moved.

Now with history merged, decide which repository is canonical and destroy the other one to avoid history diverging again.

---

If there is an overlap, that is if changes were made in the old repo *after* file were copied to E, you may have conflicts. If a lot of changes were made in the old repo after the files were copied it may be necessary to rebase off of an older commit and then treat the newer commits as a branch.

For example, let's say the files were copied to E just after B was committed to the old repo. Then later C and D were added.

```
A - B - C - D [old/master]

      E - F - G - H [master]
```

You'd rebase on top of B.

```
      C - D [old/master]
     /
A - B - E1 - F1 - G1 - H1 [master]

        E - F - G - H
```

And then treat the remaining commits on `old/master` as any other old branch.

```
git merge old/master

      C - D ---------------   [old/master]
     /                     \
A - B - E1 - F1 - G1 - H1 - J [master]

        E - F - G - H
```

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try this but it looks promising, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure if this will work since you have copied the repositories manually. This works if you have to repositories where you copied one of the repositories at one point and the commits have the same commit hash. Buts might be worth a try.

In your old repository:

```
Git remote add [name] <url to the new repo>
```

Now in your old repository (origin) you will have all the history to the point where you lost it and the new repository (the name you gave it in [name] in git remote add….) where you have all the new commits.

Now simply place yourself on latest commit on the master branch in the old repo and do a

```
Git merge [name]/master
```

(or whatever your master branch is named)

The idea is to try to get something like this:

[image]